# Using a cocoa command line application in Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, cocoa, command-line-tool

I'm writing a command line tool in Objective-C (within xCode) that uses the Foundation Framework. I have to use Objective-C because I need to unarchive objects previously archived by NSKeyedArchiver.

My question is, I'm wondering if I can now use this compiled application on my Linux web server.

I'm not sure if there would be a runtime issue or if the executable could be its own standalone program that could actually run on my Linux server.

I'd appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [The Cocotron](http://cocotron.org/) to build your app targeted to Linux.  It is an actual Cocoa implementation meant to fully interoperate (although it's not 100% complete of course), as opposed to GNUstep which is not meant to work that way.  I use this and it is awesome.

Comment: Is Cocotron active? There seems to have been no blog activity for over 2 years which doesn't fill me with confidence. I've looked at GNUstep in the past too and they both seem like interesting projects in need of some extra love and TLC.

Comment: @Roger: there are still active commits going in in the Cocotron source tree, so I guess it's still active.

Comment: It's very active, and very capable - if you check the google code page you can see that.  It's got a learning curve but it's great once you get going.  A lot of people see the webpage and think it's out of date and have trouble finding up to date info - I've started to put together a user's guide but it's not even at a draft yet.. eventually it will exist!

Comment: @nektarios, @JeremyP thanks both for the info, looks like it's worth another look after all. It's a very interesting idea and just the sort of thing we might be interested in for a couple of projects ...

Comment: @Roger I agree - it's worth the time to investigate, I am using it for cross-platform development and have changed my project framework to use it for everything I plan to do for quite some time.  Many other people are very invested as well so it's not going anywhere

Comment: @Roger Feel free to contact the project founder (and other developers) on [the Cocotron Developers Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/cocotron-dev/).

Comment: Cocotron looks very promising. Does it work with XCode4? Is there any sort of decent tutorial out there you know of? I've been looking around but can't find anything worthwhile.

Comment: @Dan - It does work with Xcode 4 and you can see my notes here -> http://groups.google.com/group/cocotron-dev/browse_thread/thread/432df56ac3e62fe8?pli=1 where I get a crosscompiler built under Xcode 4 for FreeBSD (similar for Linux, Windows, Solaris..)  Xcode 4 w/Cocotron is my environment and working great

Comment: @Dan and past that, there's no tutorial really, other than go here: http://cocotron.org/Tools/InstallCDT  and install your CDT then grab the source of Cocotron: http://cocotron.org/Code  and compile it as I describe in that mailing list.  The CDT builds crosscompilers which is step 1, step 2 is getting the Cocotron source and actually building its libraries (Foundation for example).  Step 3 is including those built cocotron frameowrks in your project and compiling with the crosscompilers, resulting in a binary for your target platform.

Comment: Thank you Nektarios. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I believe that it only targets for 100% compatibility with 10.4/10.5.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot run a program that was compiled on and for a Mac on a Linux system. So you will have to compile it for (and on) Linux. Apple's Foundation framework is not available for Linux, but have a look at [GNUstep](http://gnustep.org/), a free and open Cocoa implementation.

I don't know if GNUstep can read archives that have been archived with Cocoa's `NSKeyedArchiver`, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have provided a wrap-up on how to [compile a command line tool based on the Cocotron Foundation framework](http://blog.tlensing.org/2011/06/07/cocotron-and-xcode4-how-to-run-objective-c-apps-on-linux-part-2/) on my blog.

This does also include a step by step guide on [how to cross compile the Foundation framework for Ubuntu Linux](http://blog.tlensing.org/2011/05/01/cocotron-and-xcode4-how-to-run-objective-c-apps-on-linux/).

Hope this is helpful!